# When does the quarantinethreshold counter reset in WSFC cluster?

Tags: sql-server-2016, availability-groups, clustering

An outage that occurred on our SQL availability group this morning caused us to look into the quarantine settings on WSFC - something we never needed to configure.

Now there seems to only be two settings:

QuarantineDuration: 7200 - the number of seconds a node is quarantined for when it's quarantined
QuarantineThreshold: 3 - the number of times a node's taken out of the cluster (or flaps) before a quarantine is applied on it.

Now that's all well and good, but let's say the flapping stops at 2 times. How long before the Threshold counter is reset to 0? Surely it gets reset at some point. If not, then the next time this happens, let's say in a month's time, then it'd get immediately quarantined the first time, which doesn't really make any sense.

I can't seem to find anything in the WSFC documentation. Does anyone know?